# R iterating by group and mapping values based on column value

Tags: r, non-equi-join

I have the following data frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end'),
                 time = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31),
                 target = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 comb = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1))
```

And another data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(time = c(2,5,8,14,14,20,21,26,28,28),
                   name = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'))
```

So, if we take a look at `df` we could sort the data by target and combination and we will notice that there are basically "groups". For example for `target=1` and `comb=0` there are four entries `p1_start,p1_end,p2_start,p2_end` and it is the same for all other target/comb combinations.
On the other side `data` contains entries with `time` being a timestamp.

**Goal**: I want to map the values from both data frames based on `time`.
**Example**: The first entry of `data` has `time=2` meaning it happened between `p1_start`,`p1_end` so it should get the values `target=1` and `comb=0` mapped to the `data` data frame.
**Example 2**: The entries of `data` with `time=14` happened between `p2_start`,`p2_end` so they should get the values `target=1` and `comb=1` mapped to the `data` data frame.

**Idea**: I thought I iterate over `df` by `target` and `comb` and for each combination of them check if there are rows in `data` whose time is between. The second could be done with the following command:

```
data[which(data$time > p1_start & data$time < p2_end),]
```

once I get the rows it is easy to append the values.
**Problem**: how could I do the iteration? I tried with the following:

```
df %>% 
group_by(target, comb) %>% 
print(data[which(data$time > df$p1_start & data$time < df$p2_end),])
```

But I am getting an error that `time` has not been initialized

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best known as performing *non-equi join*. We need to find a range in some given dataframe that corresponds to each value in one or more given vectors. This is better handled by the `data.table` package.

We would first transform your `df` into a format suitable for performing the join and then join `data` with `df` by `time <= end` while `time >= start`. Here is the code

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, c("type", "name") := tstrsplit(name, "_", fixed = TRUE)]
df <- dcast(df, ... ~ name, value.var = "time")

cols <- c("target", "comb", "type")
setDT(data)[df, (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols)), on = .(time<=end, time>=start)]
```

After `dcast`, `df` looks like this

```
   target comb type end start
1:      1    0   p1   3     1
2:      1    0   p2   7     5
3:      1    1   p1  11     9
4:      1    1   p2  15    13
5:      2    0   p1  19    17
6:      2    0   p2  23    21
7:      2    1   p1  27    25
8:      2    1   p2  31    29
```

And the output is

```
> data
    time name target comb type
 1:    2    a      1    0   p1
 2:    5    b      1    0   p2
 3:    8    c     NA   NA <NA>
 4:   14    d      1    1   p2
 5:   14    e      1    1   p2
 6:   20    f     NA   NA <NA>
 7:   21    g      2    0   p2
 8:   26    h      2    1   p1
 9:   28    i     NA   NA <NA>
10:   28    j     NA   NA <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rename(name_df=name) %>% 
  mutate(x = time +1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(time, x), 
    names_to = "helper",
    values_to = "time"
  ) %>% 
  right_join(data, by="time") %>% 
  select(time, name, target, comb)
```

```
    time name  target  comb
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2 a          1     0
 2     5 b          1     0
 3     8 c          1     0
 4    14 d          1     1
 5    14 e          1     1
 6    20 f          2     0
 7    21 g          2     0
 8    26 h          2     1
 9    28 i          2     1
10    28 j          2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c('p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end','p1_start','p1_end','p2_start','p2_end'),
                 time = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31),
                 target = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 comb = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1))

data <- data.frame(time = c(2,5,8,14,14,20,21,26,28,28),
                   name = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'))

library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- df %>%
  separate(name,
           into = c("p", "period"),
           sep = "_",
           remove = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(p, target, comb),
    names_from = period,
    values_from = time
  ) %>%
  select(-p)

fuzzy_left_join(
  x = data, 
  y = tmp, 
  by = c("time" = "start", 
         "time" = "end"), 
  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
#>    time name target comb start end
#> 1     2    a      1    0     1   3
#> 2     5    b      1    0     5   7
#> 3     8    c     NA   NA    NA  NA
#> 4    14    d      1    1    13  15
#> 5    14    e      1    1    13  15
#> 6    20    f     NA   NA    NA  NA
#> 7    21    g      2    0    21  23
#> 8    26    h      2    1    25  27
#> 9    28    i     NA   NA    NA  NA
#> 10   28    j     NA   NA    NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>